# Find and update specific duplicates in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, duplicates

given below table:

```
+----+---------+-----------+-------------+-------+
| ID |  NAME   | LAST NAME |    PHONE    | STATE |
+----+---------+-----------+-------------+-------+
|  1 | James   | Vangohg   | 04333989878 | NULL  |
|  2 | Ashly   | Baboon    | 09898788909 | NULL  |
|  3 | James   | Vangohg   | 04333989878 | NULL  |
|  4 | Ashly   | Baboon    | 09898788909 | NULL  |
|  5 | Michael | Foo       | 02933889990 | NULL  |
|  6 | James   | Vangohg   | 04333989878 | NULL  |
+----+---------+-----------+-------------+-------+
```

I want to use MS SQL to find and update duplicate (based on name, last name and number) but only the earlier one(s). So desired result for above table is:

```
+----+---------+-----------+-------------+-------+
| ID |  NAME   | LAST NAME |    PHONE    | STATE |
+----+---------+-----------+-------------+-------+
|  1 | James   | Vangohg   | 04333989878 | DUPE  |
|  2 | Ashly   | Baboon    | 09898788909 | DUPE  |
|  3 | James   | Vangohg   | 04333989878 | DUPE  |
|  4 | Ashly   | Baboon    | 09898788909 | NULL  |
|  5 | Michael | Foo       | 02933889990 | NULL  |
|  6 | James   | Vangohg   | 04333989878 | NULL  |
+----+---------+-----------+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: When you say "mark", are you asking for an `update` query that would change the `STATE` column in the table (so a one-time DML operation) or a `select` statement that could just retrieve the duplicates (with or without the rest of the data)?

Comment: I did meant to UPDATE the state column. I will update the question

Comment: People seem to be a bit confused about what you're asking. Further text in the question might clarify, but it seemed pretty clear to me.

Comment: @Mazzi It is still not clear what you want really. I did one last try. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query uses a CTE to apply a row number, where any number > 1 is a dupe of the row with the highest ID.

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT ID,NAME,[LAST NAME],PHONE,STATE,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NAME,[LAST NAME],PHONE ORDER BY ID DESC) 
  FROM dbo.YourTable
)
UPDATE x SET STATE = CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN NULL ELSE 'DUPE' END;
```

Of course, I see no reason to actually update the table with this information; every time the table is touched, this data is stale and the query must be re-applied. Since you can derive this information at run-time, this should be part of a query, not constantly updated in the table. IMHO.

Comment: +1. Interesting; I wasn't aware that you could perform an update on a CTE.

Comment: @peter.petrov: Any statement preceding a CTE needs to end with a semicolon. Since you can have as many semicolons as you like with no actual code between them, prefixing a CTE with a semicolon is a safe way to ensure that the previous statement has been terminated.

Comment: @peter.petrov yes, see https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons.aspx

Comment: I am sorry, I am not too familiar with CTE, would x be the name of the block and irrelevant as what it can be named?
btw, the table is mostly read oriented so this dedupe would happen rarely.

Comment: @Mazzi yes, you can change `x` to `cte` or `my_common_table_expression` or any other valid identifier you like. Just make sure you change it in both places. Please [read here for more information on CTEs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try this statement.

**LAST UPDATE:**

```
update t1
set
t1.STATE = 'DUPE'

from 

TableName t1

join 
(
    select name, last_name, phone, max(id) as id, count(id) as cnt
    from
    TableName
    group by name, last_name, phone
    having count(id) > 1
) t2 on ( t1.name = t2.name and t1.last_name = t2.last_name and t1.phone = t2.phone and t1.id < t2.id)
```

Comment: Downvoted because, as with the other similar answer, this will not update all of the rows that have multiple duplicates. It only updates the OLDEST duplicate. It will also update rows that have no duplicate.

Comment: @AdamRobinson Updated. How about now? :) Check carefully.

Comment: @AdamRobinson No, my initial version was OK. It would update only the earliest one.

Comment: Unfortunately this still won't work. This will update the LATEST duplicate (which seems to be the one he wants to keep, looking at the example and his description). It will still also update rows that have no duplicate at all.

Comment: No, I'm afraid it wasn't. As I explained, it would *only* update the earliest one (what if there were three rows with the same values?) and it would update rows that had no duplicate at all.

Comment: The latter point is fixed. The former is not; the query does not handle cases where a given combination of name, last name, and phone exists more than twice.

Comment: @AdamRobinson It was written in the question that he wants to update only the earliest.

Comment: @AdamRobinson "having count(id) > 1" ?!

Comment: No, the question says "but only the earlier one(s)". Not "only the earliest one".

Comment: @AdamRobinson Last try. Is it fixed now?

Comment: @AdamRobinson Wow. Finally. OK. Thanks btw.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of your requirements is correct, you want to update all of the `STATE` values to `DUPE` when there exists another row with a higher `ID` value that has the same `NAME` and `LAST NAME`. If so, use this:

```
update t set STATE = (case when sorted.RowNbr = 1 then null else 'DUPE' end)

from yourtable t

join (select 
          ID, 
          row_number() over 
              (partition by name, [last name], phone order by id desc) as RowNbr from yourtable) 

     sorted on sorted.ID = t.ID
```

Comment: Wasn't me, but not syntactically correct (the derived table `sorted` is missing a `FROM` clause). Also you can do this more simply without a self-join (see my answer for example).

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Good catch; I've added the `from` clause.